# Incomplete android appcompat fragmentsupport: missing resource divider_horizontal_bright_opaque.9.png

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-resources, android-appcompat

When I run a wizard generated andorid app on Android 2.2 (Froyo) I get a runtime exception telling me that

> resource `divider_horizontal_bright_opaque.9.png` is not found
>
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class
>
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:
>   File res/drawable-mdpi/divider_horizontal_bright_opaque.9.png from drawable resource ID #0x0

What I expected:

- the missing resource `divider_horizontal_bright_opaque.9.png`
- is referenced by the non-usergenerated-code
- which should be included in the library/aar `com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0` or `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0`
- which should be included into the app by the gradle build.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

How to reproduce:

Using android studio 0.5.9 wizard I created an Android Application with these settings

- minimum required sdk `api8: Android 2.2 (Froyo)`
- target sdk: `api19: Android 4.4 (KitKat)`
- compile with: `api19: Android 4.4 (KitKat)`
- Theme : `Holo Light with Dark Action Bar`
- selected checkboxes Create Activity [X], Fragments [X], ActionBar[X]
- Activity-Type: `Master/Detail Flow`

This is the gradle build fils

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        packageName "com.example.tests.android.gui"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
}
```

the build was made with

- gradle 1.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating a minimum `android.support.v4.app.ListFragment` app with no dependency to `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` i still got the same android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException. So the problem must be related to com.android.support:support-v4 - 
 FragmentSupport that references

- res/drawable-mdpi/divider_horizontal_bright_opaque.9.png and
- res/drawable-hdpi/divider_horizontal_bright_opaque.9.png

On my machine i found

under ".../platforms/android-7/data/res/drawable-mdpi/divider_horizontal_bright_opaque.9.png"

the missing file and added it to my app.

After that the `v4.app.ListFragment` app is working

[Update]
the `divider_horizontal_bright_opaque.9.png` must have become some global android resource, because a second android app that uses the same libs doesn-t crash any more after the first app with the missing files was installed.